# html5 upload directory does not work in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Trying to upload folders using html5 tag “. It works in chrome with webkitdirectory attribute but not working IE 11. In IE 11 I cannot upload a directory with with “msdirectory” 
attribute. Here is the simple example to browse the folder (works in chrome),

http://jsfiddle.net/9ztae6m6/3/

```
sample example
```

It would be great if anyone can help me.

Comment: It works on my machine https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67763500/IE11.PNG

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker No it does not. You cannot select whole folders, while in Chrome you can.